# CheckBox in GridView failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I've read through about 50 sites and stackoverflow questions that advise to do what I have in my code below. I've been through many variations on this, and I can't seem to get it to do anything at all.

I've been watching SQL Profiler and nothing is sent at all. 
I get no errors.

All I want is a list with checkboxes I can click to change a single setting from 0 to 1. I'm sure it's me, but I'm missing it, and I've spent an embarrassingly long time on this. Thanks for any input.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="npi" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="provcode" HeaderText="provcode" 
                SortExpression="provcode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="npi" HeaderText="npi" SortExpression="npi" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="firstname" HeaderText="firstname" 
                SortExpression="firstname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="lastname" HeaderText="lastname" 
                SortExpression="lastname" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Submit Y/N">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="submitChk" runat="server" Enabled="true" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckChanged="submit_CheckedChanged"
                       Checked='<%# Bind("submit") %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
<br />

<p>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DS_SSRS_ReportsConnectionString1 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [provcode], [npi], [firstname], [lastname], [submit] 
                       FROM [DRPprovders]
                       ORDER BY lastname, firstname"
        onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" 
        >
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</p>
```

CodeBehind:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public partial class Pages_ProvSelect : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{

}

protected void submit_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox submitChk = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)submitChk.NamingContainer;
    //int ID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[row.DataItemIndex].Value;
    String npi = (String)GridView1.DataKeys[row.DataItemIndex].Value;

}
```

}

Comment: your code do not anything! explain more..

Comment: Why do you think NamingContainer hold a row of data?

Comment: @N4TKD, I couldn't say. I was just following several examples I found where others were doing what I need to do. I've never personally used NamingContainer, but that was what others were suggesting so I gave it a shot.

Comment: @mehdi, There's not a great deal to explain. It's a page with only a grid pulling a small table in it. The column with the checkbox (submit) is set to autopostback and use the submit_CheckedChanged event in the codebehind. That event was written using examples from others.

Comment: @R_Scott Best step is to debug it walk through the code see what is what I think NamingContainer holds the id of the control just off top of my head.

Comment: Are you open to changing your approach?  If you used the standard GridView workflow (button to put GridViewRow into edit mode, buttons to submit or cancel update), this would be a lot simpler.  NamingContainer is the right property, but it's kind of a messy approach.  By the way, the problem is that you are not making a database call in the "submit_CheckedChanged" method.

Comment: @N4TKD FYI - the `.NamingContainer` property of a control is its first parent control that implements the INamingContainer interface. Since GridViewRow does implement that interface, the `.NamingContainer` property of a field in a GridView will contain a reference to a GridViewRow control (unless there are nested "naming container" controls involved, which is why this is not an ideal approach - although you do see it a lot on forums and such a shortcut / workaround).

Comment: @jadarnel27, I am more than willing to change my approach, but I was hoping to avoid the standard workflow. There will be roughly 150 items in the grid for the user to enable/disable the checkbox (submit field) so my hope was to be able to allow them to just click each once rather than click edit, click the box, click update. That might have to do for now, though.

Comment: Ah, that's understandable.  Be careful about changing the structure of your Templatefield then - if you nest that CheckBox inside another INamingContainer control (like an `<asp:Panel>`, for instance), it will break your code.  So keep that in mind, is all =)

Comment: I just realized I had OnCheckChanged in my checkbox control instead of OnCheckedChanged. That's why nothing was happening. The event was never firing. It doesn't solve my problem yet, but it's something. I'm going to look at jadarnel27's solution below to see if I can make this work. Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to connect to the database and perform the update "manually" in that CheckedChanged method.

Something like this should work:

```
protected void submit_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox submitChk = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)submitChk.NamingContainer;
    String npi = (String)GridView1.DataKeys[row.DataItemIndex].Value;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string here");
    string updateQuery = "UPDATE DRPprovders SET submit = @submit WHERE npi = @npi";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, conn);

    // If it's checked, pass 1, else pass 0
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@submit", submitChk.Checked ? 1 : 0);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@npi", npi);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

You might just be able to pass the boolean value of submitChk.Checked (rather than converting to 1's and 0's like I did), I can't remember now (and I was just typing this off the top of my head, so it's untested).

Comment: That actually may need to be `submitChk.Checked ? "1" : "0"`  Man, I'm rusty on this stuff.  I'm too used to using ORMs at this point.

Comment: After I found my stupid typo, I used your solution, and that did it. Exactly what I wanted. Thank you for your time. It's greatly appreciated.